# Submit button click does not work after loadContent in JavaFX2

Tags: javafx-2

I am loading a url through javafx web engine.load(url). My requirement was to modify the embedded HTML when the page loads to have the fonts loaded properly by changing the source of the fonts. I was able to get the document object and convert to string and replace the appropriate sections and then load the HTML back with **webengine.loadContent(string)**. However, once the page comes up and click on the submit button nothing happens. Below is my code through which all of this happens:

```
  webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        String htmlBody = null;
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue, Worker.State prevState, Worker.State newState) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            //String htmlBody = null;
            int count = 0;
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                browser.requestFocus();
                // Get the document object from Engine.
                Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
                try {
                    // Use Transformer to convert the HTML Object from the document top String format.
                    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
                    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
                    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

                    StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
                    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),new StreamResult(outWriter));
                    StringBuffer sb = outWriter.getBuffer();
                    htmlBody = sb.toString();

                    // Replace the font-family attribute in the style section to the actual URL of the font being used.
                    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace("font-family: medium", "font-family: url(http://1.10.30.45:8080/fonts/Md.ttf)");
                     observableValue.removeListener(this); 

                    // Load the new HTML string to the Engine.
                    webEngine.loadContent(htmlBody, "text/html");


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    webEngine.load(url);
    //add the web view to the scene
    getChildren().add(browser);
```

If i remove the below 2 lines, i am able to click on the login button and move to the welcome page.
                        observableValue.removeListener(this);

```
                    // Load the new HTML string to the Engine.
                    webEngine.loadContent(htmlBody, "text/html");
```

But in this case the actual fonts are changed to some default fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom font loading issue is resolved with jdk 8 with latest version of javafx. the version in jdk 1.8.0 is **javafx.runtime.version=8.0.0**

Earlier with JDK 1.7.0_45 it was **javafx.runtime.version=2.2.45**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the HTML/Javascript code run when you press the submit button? What is the `action` attribute of the relevant form? I suspect that because of the `webEngine.loadContent()` call, the page does not know *where* to submit the form, that is why it is not working.

There is a possibility that your style issue can be remedied by loading the page as normal and using the `userStyleSheetLocation` property of `WebEngine` to manually set a stylesheet ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#userStyleSheetLocationProperty)). I'd suggest you experimented a bit with the `userStyleSheetLocation`.

Comment: i tried with the userStyleSheetLocation earlier but was unable to override the already applied css to the page. However, the font issue was resolved today when i used jdk 8 with the latest version of javaFX.